# Can I travel to Italy with my Carta d’identita?

Tags: identity-cards

I live in the UK and a holder of an Italian “residence card of a family member of a union citizen”, I’ve been given an appointment to renew my residence card in Italy, since it’s expired. Can I travel to Italy with my Carta d’identita??? (It’s written at the back of my Carta d’identita that it can’t be used for expatriation purposes)

Comment: Allthough not asked, the questions arise: What is the citizenship of your spouse and if your spouse presently resides in an EU country? What is your spouses residence status in Italy?

Comment: “I live in the UK and want to renew my residence card in Italy”. Puzzling.

Comment: Are you expecting to return live in Italy?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the Carta di identità states **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO** (which should be understood as NOT VALID FOR TRAVEL), then it was issued to a 3rd country national and is not considered a travel document (only those that are issued to Italian citizens are).

You must use your Passport.

Please add your citizenship to the question.

> [Council of the European Union - PRADO - ITA-BO-04004](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-BO-04004/index.html):
> Second version: identity card which is not valid for travel (marked "NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO")
> [image]